# Access 2002 - how to link two data entry forms?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2002

I have a form for users to enter contact (customer) details, and I want to add a separate form to enable users to add phone numbers to the data.  They would open the second form by clicking on a button.  Contact details are stored in a contact table keyed on contact_id.  The telephone numbers are stored in a telephone table keyed on phone_id with a foreign key of contact_id.

I have created the forms, but I cannot see how I can link the form handling phone numbers with its parent, the contact details form.  Any insights here would be appreciated.

Comment: Three ways to do this: (1) Create a subform on your main form that will show phone numbers for which ever customer is 'current'; (2) When user clicks button, pass the ID as the 'OpenArgs' parameter of your DoCmd.OpenForm... then use that value to filter that form; (3) save the ID as a global variable, then when form opens grab the ID.

Comment: I would generally prefer the WHERE argument to the OpenArgs argument of the OpenForm method ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx )